# Progress bar not working because of freezing window win visual c++

Tags: visual-c++, progress-bar

I got a program made where I calculates some data. I got a process that iterate some nodes. I have added a progress bar to show some info about the process while computing, but it is not working. Before starting the process the bar is set to 0, and when it finishes it's full, but it just jumps from 0 to 100. I think it is because the window form freezes while it is computing, and I have no idea how to avoid this situation. Any clues?
The code about the bar:

```
         progressBar1->Minimum=0;
         progressBar1->Maximum=100;
         for( i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
             progressBar1->Value = i;
             progressBar1->Refresh();
         }
```

Thanks!

Comment: I know you said you have no clue, but you need to try something.

Comment: What should I try so?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know C++. but generally when I come across an error I think of things that may be causing it (like you have done) and modify some code to test my theories.

Answer (score 0):

Progress bar will not get updated this way, at least it wont appear interactively to the user. The reason is simple, you are not allowing the UI message-loop to process your message. Windows has its message-pump, which must be processed to display the UI. When you say `Value = 10`, for example, it sends the message to the UI-message-loop, but you don't allow it to process, and you send another message. This way UI keeps freezing.

A alternative, and better way, is to create a separate thread to run your loop. And from that thread, call the methods to update the UI. You would appreciate reading [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43994/The-Practical-Guide-to-Multithreading-Part-1). Though it doesn't cover .NET in C++, but will clear most of the things.

Comment: I was minding on the threading matter... Thanks a lot, I will tell you later what I got ;)

Comment: You might use GetMessage-PeekMessage-DispatchMessage functions, if you don't want to use threads. But that's not good idea!